# If $\frac{x^2-bx}{ax-c} = \frac{k-1}{k+1}$ has roots, whose magnitude is equal but signs are opposite.

Tags: quadratics

> If $\frac{x^2-bx}{ax-c} = \frac{k-1}{k+1}$ has roots, whose magnitude is equal but signs are opposite.

Answer is $\frac{a-b}{a+b}$

I used cross multiplication and since the roots are opposite in sign, on adding the roots, the total must be zero. But this is a long method. 
Please tell me any shorter method to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we need the value of $k,$

$$(k+1)x^2-x[b(k+1)-a(k-1)]+c(k-1)=0$$

So, if $\alpha$ is a root, $-\alpha$ will be the other

$$\implies  \alpha+(-\alpha)=\dfrac{b(k+1)-a(k-1)}{k+1}$$

$$\implies\dfrac{k-1}{k+1}= \dfrac ab$$

Apply [Componendo et Dividendo](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm)

Comment: I am getting $ \frac{k+1}{k-1} x^2 -x(b\frac{k+1}{k-1} -a) -c =0 $

Comment: @user168282, Please find the updated answer